# Bring View on top of Modal using zIndex style with React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

`zIndex` has been introduced recently to React-Native to change the position of a `View` in the stack of layers.

Although, I'm not able to bring a `View` on top of a `Modal` component.

My code looks like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal visible>
        {props.children}
      </Modal>
      <View style={{ zIndex: 1000 }}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I guess I could stop using `<Modal>` and create a regular animated `<View>` that would behave like the `Modal`, but I'd rather find another solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Still no solution in 2019?

Comment: Still no solution in 2022?

Comment: Still no solution in 2022? x2

Comment: I managed to show a loading overlay by adding `<Modal>` with transparent attribute true, inside the modal.

Answer (score 26):

No amount of `zIndex` manipulation will bring something above a react-native `Modal`, unfortunately. The `Modal` component is a native view that sits on top of the rest of your react-native application. The only way to put something above it is to put something in the modal itself, or alternately to use a js only implementation of a Modal.

Incidentally, the react-native-community version of modal is also built on the react-native modal, so would have the same issue. There's a discussion about different js implementation here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/issues/145

Answer (score 4):

Not possible with modal. As the modal should always shown regardless of whatever the zIndex is given to it and other components in the screen

It will always shown you unless you make visible=false

To implement what you want. You could use a absolutely positioned view with some zIndex trick to move this view back and front.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
       <View style={{position:'absolute',top:0,bottom:0,left:0,right:0,zIndex:visible?-1:2}}>
          {props.children}
       </View>
       <View style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
  modal: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 0, // This is the important style you need to set
    alignItems: undefined,
    justifyContent: undefined,
  }

<Modal isVisible={true} style={styles.modal}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>Hello!</Text>
 </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `react-native-modal`

I set the API `coverScreen` to `false` and then updated the `zIndex` of `<View>` to bring it on top.

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling with the same problem and finally, I solved it. here's what I found:

**First, the problem:**
The issue arises when you open two modals simultaneously. The app stacks them on top of each other randomly, depending on the modal rendering time. Consequently, the last modal to finish rendering appears on top of the first one that completed rendering earlier. As a result, you may observe your modal positioned behind the other one.

**Second, the solution:**
to make the second modal opens on the first modal you need to arrange the order of the modals opening, which means you open the parent modal then open the child modal.
and for doing that I'm using promise which allows me to do that like this steps example:-

1 - create promise

```
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState({ backDrop: false, modal: false }); // modals open state

function openDialog() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setOpen((previous) => ({ ...previous, backDrop: props.isOpen }))
        resolve()
    })
}
```

2 - I use `useEffect()` to trigger modal opening props and then invoke an async function which will await the `openDialog()` function at the first step above and then will set open state after the first function invoked.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
        await openDialog()
        setOpen((previous) => ({ ...previous, modal: props.isOpen }))
    }())
}, [props.isOpen])
```

this how you can control opening the modals pre-arranged and on top of each other

Answer (score -5):

You have to change the z-index of the modal not the one of the view (and a z-index of value `1` would suffice):

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal visible style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
        {props.children}
      </Modal>
      <View>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)).

**EDIT:**

Another solution is to change the order of the elements:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
      <Modal visible>
        {props.children}
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

With this solution you don't need `z-index` because the modal is already on top of the view.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I have a zIndex of 1 on my modal and 10 on my loading view.

Comment: You have to swap them. The greater is the `z-index`, the "higher" the element is in the view hierarchy. Try to put a `z-index` of 10 on your modal.

Comment: I cannot change the order of elements in my case unfortunately :(

Comment: OP is trying to overlay a view on top of the modal, not the other way around (which is default)

Comment: this won't work since the modal will always be on top of your "application"