# Make drawer visible when modal on. React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I'm developing project on react-native, my problem is that modal is over the drawer navigator, I tried set zIndex but it is useless.

My modal:

```
    <Modal visible={isVisible} animationType={'fade'} transparent={true}>
      <Animated.View style={{ marginTop: marginTop, zIndex: 0 }}>
          ...
      </Animated.View>
    </Modal>
```

My drawer:

```
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} style={{ marginTop: -5 }}>
      <ImageBackground source={back} style={{...s.drawerContainer, zIndex: 100}}>
         ...
      </ImageBackground>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
```

[image: rea]
here is screenshot, I need to set drawer over this modal

Answer (score 1):

The modal is natively on top of everything, check this question as well: [Bring View on top of Modal using zIndex style with React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766350/bring-view-on-top-of-modal-using-zindex-style-with-react-native)

You cannot put the drawer above it unfortunately.